# Connect Airbyte in Docker container to local postgres db instance

Tags: postgresql, docker, airbyte

I recently setup an instance of Airbyte on my local machine using a Docker container.  I also have a local instance of Postgres running which I would like to use as a data source in Airbyte.  It seems like I cannot connect to the local Postgres instance because of the Docker container.  Any thoughts on how to establish this connectivity?

Answer (score 8):

I joined the Airbyte Slack channel and was told to use **host.docker.internal** instead of "localhost" or "127.0.0.1" and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.
Is it difficult to issue a URL for external publication when using ngrok?

ngrok tcp 5432

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).